# geometric series with negative exponent

Tags: geometric-series

I wonder if it is possible to convert the infinite geometric series with negative exponent to a  positive one? Is the calculation is correct ?

∑_(n=1)^∞▒x^(-n) =∑_(n=1)^∞▒〖(〖1/x)〗^n 〗=1/(1-1/x)=x/(x-1)

The pic is attached.

[image]

Comment: Yes it is correct!

Comment: While I agree that the idea is correct, be aware that you need $|x|>1$ for it to work. Otherwise, it will not converge.

Comment: yes! Ihave the same condition.Thank you

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is correct.

$1^\mathrm{st}$ step:

$$
x^{-n} = \left(\frac{1}{x}\right)^n
$$
Here one can discuss whether $x\ne0$ must be, but this condition is contained in the next step anyway, which is why the discussion is also superfluous.

$2^\mathrm{nd}$ step:

If $|q|<1$:

$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{q^n}=\frac{1}{1-q}
$$

Therefore, if $|\frac{1}{x}|<1 \Rightarrow |x|>1$

$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)^n}=\frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{x}}
$$

$3^\mathrm{rd}$ step:

$$
\frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{x}}=\frac{1}{\frac{x}{x}-\frac{1}{x}}=\frac{1}{\frac{x-1}{x}}=\frac{x}{x-1}
$$

Put all steps together:

$$
|x|>1\quad\Rightarrow\quad\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{x^{-n}}=\frac{x}{x-1}
$$

Answer (score 0):

The function $\frac{1}{1-x}$ has a pole at $x=1$, with

$$\lim_\limits{n\to 1^+} \frac{1}{1-x} = -\infty$$

$$\lim_\limits{n\to 1^-} \frac{1}{1-x} = \infty$$

For the reciprocal geometric series to work, we must have $|x|>1$.

The final result is valid, but requires $|x|<1$ to be expandable as a MacLaurin series.